# Spring Cloud Kafka Stream Unable to create Producer Config Error

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have two Spring boot project with Kafka-stream dependencies, they have exactly same dependencies in gradle and exactly same configurations, yet one of the project when started logs error  as below

```
11:35:37.974 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.k.c.admin.AdminClientConfig - AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [192.169.0.109:6667]
    client.id = client
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 120000
    retries = 5
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS

11:35:38.017 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 1.0.0
11:35:38.017 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : aaa7af6d4a11b29d
11:35:38.136 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner - Using kafka topic for outbound: createschedule
11:36:08.147 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.c.stream.binding.BindingService - Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: provisioning exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:243)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:126)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:71)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:77)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:244)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:221)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:46)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:47)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at com.und.ClientPanelApplicationKt.main(ClientPanelApplication.kt:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:236)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

I am using kotlin 2.30, and Spring Release 2.0.0.0
Relevant part of my build gradle is  below

```
ext {
    kotlinVersion = '1.2.30'
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M8'
}

dependencies{
  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka')
}
```

I have defined one  OutPut channel as below

```
interface EventStream {

    @Output("createschedule")
    fun outputEvent(): MessageChannel

}
```

Below is relvant section of my code where i have defined sender and listener

```
@Service
class TestService {



    @Autowired
    private lateinit var eventStream: EventStream

    fun test() {
        processSchedule("Hello")
    }






    @SendTo("createschedule")
    fun processSchedule(campaign: String): String {
        return campaign
    }

    @StreamListener("createschedule")
    fun listenSchedule(campaign: String) {
        println(campaign)
        //return campaign
    }

}
```

Below is relevant section of my application.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${KAFKA_IP}
          defaultBrokerPort: ${KAFKA_PORT}
          zkNodes: ${ZK_IP}
          defaultZkPort: ${ZK_PORT}
        bindings:
          createschedule:
            group: createscheduleGroup
            destination: createschedule
            consumer:
              group: createscheduleGroup



  kafka:
    admin:
      properties:
        #security.protocol: SSL
        client.id: client
```

As i already stated it throw error while starting and after it starts it keep throwing below error in logs

```
11:54:38.231 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner - Using kafka topic for outbound: createschedule
11:54:59.070 [kafka-admin-client-thread | client-panel] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=client-panel] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
11:55:08.234 [pool-3-thread-1] ERROR o.s.c.stream.binding.BindingService - Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: provisioning exception; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:243)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:126)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:71)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:77)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:262)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call$$$capture(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicAndPartitions(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopicIfNecessary(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:236)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you sure you have Kafka ran on the host `192.169.0.109:6667`?

Comment: @ArtemBilan yes, I have one other application running fine with almost similar config and when it starts, it automatically creates topics and able to send messages.

Comment: Strange: you show config for consumer, but error is about producer. Also the client.id is different...

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I changed client id by mistake while posting the question, although it is same in my code, will fix in question. yes, it is very strange, do you need any other details? I have struggled for 2 days before finally posting here, not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I would suggest looking at thee server logs to see if it gives you any clues. I was wondering if it's a problem with not enough brokers, but I get this in that case, not a timeout... `Failed to create topics

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 4 larger than available brokers: 3.`

Comment: @Gary Russell , no it is not an issue with not enough broker as all other my services work fines with sane Kafka server and zookeeper. And I can replicate those services multiple times with no issues, it is only with this particular services I run into problem. I am sure I am missing something very trivial, which I am unable to pinpoint any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this service use the same Kafka Client version as all others ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I haven't specificied version explicitly as version is picked from Finchley.M8, is it somehow possible different client version might get used, I will verify and inform , it could be an issue.

Comment: That's correct: it is pulled transitively. But at the same time your other services might rely on some different Kafka Client version

Comment: @ArtemBilan, i verified and all services have same client jar, commitId=aaa7af6d4a11b29d
version=1.0.0

Comment: @ArtemBilan, thanks for your inputs, I will try to do full log analysis and also check network trace to see what is happening. it could be an issue on my infra rather than a Kafka issue. thanks for your help.

Comment: Good. Please, share with us here your finding afterward. Would be great for the future experience!

Comment: I am having the same problem with springboot 2.0.4.RELEASE and spring cloud Finchley.SR1 and Confluent version 5.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem with kafka.
If you are using docker cointainers, then stop kafka, remove kafka and start kafka cointainer.